# How can I correctly map my classes (getting mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property)

Tags: java, hibernate

I realise there are already tons of questions asking about this exception message, but I've read them, the fixes offered didnt help, and they failed to address my situation: experiencing this exception message while using a class hierarchy and discrimination. I'm using hibernate 5 annotations and getting the following exception on initialisation (please forgive my class/variable name obfuscation and my comments on the lombok annotations, incase you aren't familiar with lombok):

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown
>   target entity property:
>   com.example.entity.C.a in
>   com.example.entity.A.cs

The following are my classes (with irrelevant fields removed)

```
@Entity
@Data // generates getters/setters for all fields
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class A implements Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    @NonNull
    private String id;

    @NonNull
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = PERSIST)
    private Set<C> cs;
}
```

.

```
@Data //generates getters/setters for all fields as well as toString, equals, and hashCode implementations
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor //generates a no args constructor (required by hibernate)
@AllArgsConstructor //generates a constructor with all fields present
@DiscriminatorColumn(discriminatorType = INTEGER, name = B.DISCRIMINATOR_NAME)
public abstract class B implements Persistable<UUID> {

    protected static final String DISCRIMINATOR_NAME = "direction";
    protected static final String DISCRIMINATOR_1_VALUE = "1";
    protected static final String DISCRIMINATOR_1_VALUE = "2";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID id;

    @NonNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private A a;
}
```

.

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor //generates a no args constructor (required by hibernate)
@ToString(callSuper = true) //generates toString method which calls super.toString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true) //generates equals and hashCode methods which call their respective methods in the super class
@DiscriminatorValue(B.SEND_DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE)
public class C extends B {

}
```

So, what am I doing wrong? As best as I can tell, everything is set up correctly.

Comment: How about making `a` property `protected` instead of `private`?

Comment: @Ish No effect :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that what I am trying to do is not possible and the Hibernate developers do not consider it a bug/issue. See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7635 for details.

Answer (score 0):

After closer look, I can see that you need to map your abstract classes as `@MappedSuperclass` not `@Entity` in order to get mapping to work.

Comment: But C has the getters and setters of that property inherited from B... that should suffice, right? In any case, I tried adding it to C but it didn't help.

Comment: But B is not `@MappedSupertype` it should be, insteed of @Entity

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss, that's exactly what I needed. Feel free to update your answer to suggest using `@MappedSuperclass` and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry @Antoniossss but it turns out this solution wasn't what I was looking for. `@MappedSuperclass` is used for a different usecase and doesn't work with the discriminator annotations. Any other ideas? I have a working example of this type of inheritence for a OneToOne mapping, but it doesn't seem to work for a OneToMany mapping.